# Why does OpenGL assign the same buffer to two different VAOs?

Tags: opengl, graphics, buffer, game-development

I am using `glBufferSubData` on two different VAOs with two different sets of objects (I am using instanced rendering in one of them). The problem is that when I analyze the render call with RenderDoc, I see that they are sharing the same internal buffer (which I don't think it should happen). I am for sure binding different VAOs when doing `glBufferSubData` and updating their correspondent attributes but I don't understand why OpenGL would make the two set of objects have the same buffer. Does anyone know why is this happening and if it has any solution?

In case it is useful, one of the buffers is quite big (1527864 bytes) and the other one is not small either.

Comment: Generally speaking, OpenGL does what you tell it. If the same buffer is being used for VAOs, that's because you *told it* to do that. Without your code, we can't help you. Also, you cannot use `glBufferSubData` on a VAO, since that's a buffer object manipulation function and a VAO is not a buffer object. So you seem to be confused as to what you're doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`glBufferSubData` doesn't care about VAOs, it affects buffers (a.k.a. VBOs).

If you want to put data in two different buffers, then you need to bind the first buffer with `glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER)`, call `glBufferSubData`, then bind the other buffer, and call `glBufferSubData`. (Same with `glBufferData`)

Comment: Thank you, I was using a VAO to draw just before that and I misstook it for a VBO. Changing it solved the error